# What is the right order to load angularjs, bootstrap, sp js libraries and jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, sharepoint

I have a very single app that needs to use bootstrap, ui bootstrap, angularjs and jquery.  Functionally the button below works fine, but I am not getting the styling as it should: Check alerts sample here:
http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

The html file is as follows, its a sharepoint hosted app.

```
<%-- The following 4 lines are ASP.NET directives needed when using SharePoint components --%>

<%@ Page Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" Language="C#" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

<%-- The markup and script in the following Content element will be placed in the <head> of the page --%>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
    <meta name="WebPartPageExpansion" content="full" />

    <!-- Add your CSS styles to the following file -->
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Content/App.css" />
    <link href="../Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Ad<link href="../Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />d your JavaScript to the following file -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/App.js"></script>
</asp:Content>

<%-- The markup in the following Content element will be placed in the TitleArea of the page --%>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">

</asp:Content>

<%-- The markup and script in the following Content element will be placed in the <body> of the page --%>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">

    <div class="container" ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
        <div ng-controller="AlertDemoCtrl">
          <alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}" close="closeAlert($index)">{{alert.msg}}</alert>
          <button class='btn btn-default' ng-click="addAlert()">Add Alert</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

However

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated answer**:

Nowadays the best way to handle that for Angular 2 and 4 is to use tools such as **SystemJS** or **Webpack**.

**Original answer**:

why don't you use require.js to organize your JS files into modules? 
You can define each module's dependency and they will be loaded on demand, like in sample below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>MyApp v1.0</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
<body ng-cloak>

<div id="main">
    <div class="row">
        <!--Start Content-->
            <div id="main-content" ng-view></div>
        <!--End Content-->
    </div>
</div>

<!--End Container-->
<script data-main="js/main" src="lib/requirejs/require.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

and on your main.js file you will load the dependencies:

```
require.config({    
    baseUrl: 'js/',

    paths: {        
        jquery: '../lib/plugins/jquery/jquery-2.1.0.min',
        bootstrap: '../lib/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap.min',
        angular: '../lib/components/angular/angular',
        angularCookies: '../lib/components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies',
        angularRoute: '../lib/components/angular-route/angular-route',
        myapp: '../lib/base/myapp',
    },  

    shim: {
        'jquery': {'exports': 'jquery'},
        'bootstrap' : {deps:['jquery']},
        'myapp' : {
                    deps : ['jquery', 'bootstrap', 'angular']
                },

        'angular': {
            'deps': ['jquery'],
            'exports': 'angular'
        },
        'angularResource': {
            'deps': ['angular'],
            exports: 'angularResource'
        },
        'angularRoute':{
            'deps': ['angular']
        }
    },  
    priority: [
        'angular'
    ]

});

window.name = 'NG_DEFER_BOOTSTRAP!';

require( [
    'angular',
    'app',
    'routes',
    'myapp'
], function(angular, app, routes, myapp) {
    'use strict';
    var $html = angular.element(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]);

    angular.element().ready(function() {
        angular.resumeBootstrap([app['name']]);
    });
});
```

Comment: yes but even though require.js is really lightweight it's only one JS file and you will gain the benefits of not needing to worry about the order of the files anymore.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion

```
1. jQuery - doesn't depend on other things in this list
2. Bootstrap - CSS and JS
3. AngularJS -  if angular finds jquery, it will use it in place of jqlite
4. Bootstrap UI - this has a dependency on Angular right? this is AngularUI right?
```

Comment: testing, btw, bootstrap (2) also has an acommpanion .js file

Comment: ah, yes, but if I remember correctly, it depends on jQuery

Comment: I havent looked at bootstrap ui in a while, it depends on a certain version of bootstrap doesn't it?

Comment: still doesnt render as it should :(

Comment: If you're using Angular Ui Bootstrap, you don't/shouldn't use Bootstrap's own JS.

Comment: @cvrebert - What if the app has a mix of native Bootstrap functionality along with Angular UI Bootstrap features. In that case are you saying one _still_ does not want to include both `bootstrap.js` and `ui-bootstrap.js`?

Comment: My understanding is that Angular UI Bootstrap intends to encompass "native Bootstrap"'s feature set, so my answer remains the same.